# Returning Geometry - ArcGIS REST service

Tags: geometry, arcgis-rest-api

Query Esri service won't return geometry.
I'm using a query on ArcGIS REST service, the first link returns geometry, but with the same query parameters the second link won't return geometry.

1. [First link with geometry](https://geoservices.bappenas.go.id/arcgis/rest/services/RPJMN/RancanganRPJMN2020/MapServer/0/query?where=&text=&objectIds=1&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&f=html)
2. [the second link without geometry, but it should be with geometry.](https://geoservices.bappenas.go.id/arcgis/rest/services/Data_Komoditas/Komoditas/MapServer/29/query?where=&text=&objectIds=1&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&f=html)

They both are using the same parameters, and I can assure you that the second link features have geometry ([for instance](https://geoservices.bappenas.go.id/arcgis/rest/services/Data_Komoditas/Komoditas/MapServer/29/1)).
So,
how to return geometry on the second link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcMap, bring up *Luas Lahan Sawah* layer's **Properties** dialog, and in the **Fields** tab, click to enable "**shape**". Save, and republish.

The fact that the shape field was turned off in the *Luas Lahan Sawah* layer of the Komoditas MapServer service can be seen in the screen shot below.

[image]

Contrast the above with RancanganRPJMN2020 MapServer service as below.

[image]